# owlCarousel is not a function in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, owl-carousel

I have a rails app where I'm attempting to use an owl carousel to display a list of testimonials with images.  I think I have everything set up correctly, but I'm still receiving a console error that "owlCarousel is not a function".

I have installed the gemfile correctly.

`gemfile`

```
gem 'owlcarousel-rails'
```

I'm pretty sure I have everything loaded into application.js.
`app/javascript/application.js`

```
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "controllers"
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require owl.carousel
//= require turbolinks
// require lightbox
//= require_tree .
```

Same with the application scss file:
`app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss`

```
@import "bulma";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "owl.carousel";
@import "../stylesheets/main/main.scss";

 *
 //= require jquery
 //= require jquery3
 //= require jquery_ujs
 *= require_self
 *= require owl.carousel
 */
```

This is my main view, where I have the carousel.
`app/views/main/index.html.erb`

```
<section>
  <div class="gtco-testimonials">
    <h2>Owl carousel - Client Testimonial</h2>
    <div class="owl-carousel owl-carousel1 owl-theme">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

The function that controls the carousel:
`app/assets/javascripts/testimonials.js`

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var carousels = function () {

    $(".owl-carousel1").owlCarousel({
      loop: true,
      center: true,
      margin: 0,
      responsiveClass: true,
      nav: false,
      responsive: {
        0: {
          items: 1,
          nav: false
        },
        680: {
          items: 2,
          nav: false,
          loop: false
        },
        1000: {
          items: 3,
          nav: true
        }
      }
    });
  };

  (function ($) {
    carousels();
  })(jQuery);
})();
```

Lastly, I am importing the `testimonials.js` at the bottom of `app/views/main/index.html.erb`:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "testimonials" %>
```

Comment: don't see `//= require owl.carousel` in your application.js file.

Comment: @dbugger I added it to my application.js file below the requirements for jquery, restarted my server, and I'm still seeing the "owlCarousel is not a function" error

Comment: update your question to note the changes